# How to display backslash in json object value in java - Illegal escape JSONException

Tags: java, json

How to display a backslash in json value in java. I get a org.json.JSONException: Illegal escape. at 9 with the below sample code. 
I'm using json 1.0.0 jar - org.json

```
    String s1 = "{'Hi':'\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg'}";
    int i = (int) '/';
    System.out.println(s1);
    try
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s1);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Double it, so \\\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you use wrong quotation marks, use double quotation mark in JSON:

```
String s1 = "{\"Hi\":\"\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg\"}"
```

That should work.

Comment: Yes, because you escaped the slash only for java, to do it also for the json, try use four slashes: `"{\"Hi\":\"\\\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg\"}"`

Comment: Yes but the thing is if I use 4 i get 2 backslashes I need only 1.

Comment: You get it in a parsed JSON or in your output from `System.out.println(s1);` ?

Comment: {"Hi":"\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg"}  - sysout(String)------
{"Hi":"\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg"}  - sysout(json)

Comment: If you retrieve the value from the map you will only see 1 backslash. `String s = (String) json.get("Hi");`

Comment: But do you need it parsed or in a string? Try parse the string and look at it in a debugger or get a value from the parsed json and print it

Answer (score 1):

You need two backslashes to produce one backslash in a Java string literal `"\\"`, and you need to double the backslash to get a backslash in the JSON string (since JavaScript has similar rules about backslash escapes and string literals as Java), thus, you need four backslashes:

```
String s1 = "{'Hi':'\\\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg'}";
```

If you do this:

```
String s1 = "{'Hi':'\\\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg'}";
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s1);
    System.out.println(json.get("Hi"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It prints:

> \ksdfdsfsdfdfg

Comment: That would give an output with 2 backslashes. I needed only 1.

Comment: @ThusharPSujir No, that would give an output with 1 backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 4 backslashes for this to work. If you just print the parsed json object value you will see 2 backslashes. But if you get the value from the `JSONObject` you will see only one.

```
String s1 = "{'Hi':'\\\\ksdfdsfsdfdfg'}";
int i = (int) '/';
System.out.println(s1);
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s1);
    System.out.println(json);//this will print two backslashes

    String s = (String) json.get("Hi");
    System.out.println(s);//this will print only one
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```